# A program I'm trying to run is trying to import something that apparently doesn't exist - how do I fix this?

Tags: import, aiohttp

I'm trying to run a program called vix_utils in Python (https://github.com/dougransom/vix_utils)

A jupyter notebook example file is provided for users.  As part of the initialization in the file there is a module called aiohttp which imports another module called hdrs.  In turn, hdrs tries to import "Final, Set" from "typing" which results in the following error:

```
~\Appdata\local\programs\python\python312\Lib\site-packages\vix_utils\download_vix_futures.py in <module>
----> 1 import aiohttp
      2 import asyncio
      3 import aiofiles
      4 from appdirs import user_log_dir
      5 from pathlib import Path

~\Appdata\local\programs\python\python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py in <module>
      3 from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Tuple
      4 
----> 5 from . import hdrs as hdrs
      6 from .client import (
      7     BaseConnector as BaseConnector,

~\Appdata\local\programs\python\python312\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\hdrs.py in <module>
      3 # After changing the file content call ./tools/gen.py
      4 # to regenerate the headers parser
----> 5 from typing import Final, Set
      6 
      7 from multidict import istr

ImportError: cannot import name 'Final'
```

It seems that hdrs is trying to import something that does not exist.

I tried to reinstall aiohttp, hdrs, and typing modules to clear the error but nothing changed.

I am not sure what Final and Set are or how to fix this.

Comment: Contact the author of that project to ask questions about it.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite I have done so on github but he can be a bit slow to reply sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

The typing module comes with Python, you shouldn't be trying to reinstall it (hdrs is also an internal aiohttp module, so also not sure what you think you are reinstalling).

I can only assume that you're using an old version of Python (<3.8), which is unsupported and shouldn't be used anymore. Although pip shouldn't have installed a current version of aiohttp in that case, as it has a minimum dependency of Python 3.8.

I would also note that the project you are looking at clearly states:

> You will need a Python 3.11 or later instalation [sic].

So, even 3.8 is probably too old if you want to run that project.

Comment: Thank you - I installed python 3.12 but apparently my jupyter notebook was running on python 3.5!